# fernet keep giving me Signature did not match digest

Tags: python, read-write, password-hash, fernet

I'm working on a password manager app and i want to hash passwords with Fernet, the idea is that I'm writing a password into a file hashed then retrieve it when the user asks
here is my code

note : the code works properly if there is one password in the file called secrets.txt
-the main problem is that the code not running with multi lines in secrets.txt

```
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    password = '123456789'
    write_record("facebook","ali",password,key)
    read_record(key)

def write_record(site,account,password,key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    token = f.encrypt(bytes(password,'utf-8'))
    with open ('secrets.txt','a') as file:
        file.write(f"{site},{account},{str(token)}\n")


def read_record(key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    with open ('secrets.txt','r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip().replace('\n', '')
            print("line is "+line)
            token = line.split(",")[2]
            print(token)
            token = token[2:-1]
            token = token.encode()
            print(token)
            print(f.decrypt(token))




and here is the error I'm getting




line is facebook,ali,b'gAAAAABkLyRCekwyD5p5MMmaNxee6quDhlv9zx5e6Qghfv6jjubsGtP5m5F8YaB1LEPBq90-ab1VxK5oqOHmNStNbulSBMCtXQ=='
b'gAAAAABkLyRCekwyD5p5MMmaNxee6quDhlv9zx5e6Qghfv6jjubsGtP5m5F8YaB1LEPBq90-ab1VxK5oqOHmNStNbulSBMCtXQ=='
b'gAAAAABkLyRCekwyD5p5MMmaNxee6quDhlv9zx5e6Qghfv6jjubsGtP5m5F8YaB1LEPBq90-ab1VxK5oqOHmNStNbulSBMCtXQ=='
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 119, in _verify_signature
    h.verify(data[-32:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py", line 74, in verify
    ctx.verify(signature)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py", line 75, in verify
    raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mido/Desktop/project.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mido/Desktop/project.py", line 8, in main
    read_record(key)
  File "/home/mido/Desktop/project.py", line 32, in read_record
    print(f.decrypt(token))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 80, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, time_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 137, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 121, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken



and here is the file content:

facebook,ali,b'gAAAAABkLyRCekwyD5p5MMmaNxee6quDhlv9zx5e6Qghfv6jjubsGtP5m5F8YaB1LEPBq90-ab1VxK5oqOHmNStNbulSBMCtXQ=='
facebook,ali,b'gAAAAABkLySj1RzbJMCFYrDJw8a2dNyfYMlwyiq1be818DwzU7RCWnEiUFGDS2I5DHNt7jmFf2mEm_q40h95HGfeSExTNumd-A=='
```